# database design in django for 2-rows multiple colums

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, django-models

I am trying to create a model for the following data in django.

[image]

I have around 20 columns and they can increase with time but I will only have one row for the values of each column which will update with time. What would be the best way of creating a model for such a data? I cannot transpose the rows into columns because the data is coming from another source which needs the database in the above format.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a model say TheModel (a relevent name, may be). and each column would be one attribute. This way you can add more attributes as the column increases.

According to your description, This model will have only one object. but that is fine right.

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    mda_table_ndx = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mf_p030_.._.._.. = models.IntegerField()
    ..............
    .............
```

Let us know if there is a downside to this.

Comment: The only downside to this is every time when the columns increase then the model will have to be changed. So I wanted something where the model doesnt change even if we add columns.

Comment: usually, changing model is not a big deal. everytime model changes a new migration will be created which does ground work for you. But again, If there is a better way I would love to hear. :)